# Tracing configuration for IBM MQ client does not seem to get overridden by Environment variables

Tags: .net-core, configuration, azure-functions, environment-variables, ibm-mq

I'm using the IBMMQDotnetClient NuGet package (9.3.3) and as stated [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.0?topic=multiplatforms-mq-mqi-client-configuration-file-mqclientini), you should be able to override settings defined in mqclient.ini by using environment variables. This does not seem to work when I run my app, an Azure Function app, locally.

My mqclient.ini, located in the root of my app, contains this:

```
    Trace:
        MQDotnetTraceLevel=2
        MQDotnetTracePath=C:\home\mq_traces
```

This works fine, when I attempt to connect to my MQ host I can see `.TRC` files being created in that directory.
But when I try to override these settings through my launchSettings.json, nothing changes.
launchSettings.json:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "FunctionAppWithMq": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "commandLineArgs": "--port 7222",
        "launchBrowser": false,
        "environmentVariables": {
            "MQDotnetTraceLevel": "1",
            "MQDotnetTracePath": "C:\\home\\traces_from_environment_variables"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

The trace files are still being generated in my mq_traces folder.
I know the environment settings are set correctly; when I log the values using `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable()` in one of my activity functions, I get the configured values from my launchSettings.json.

How can I get the MQ client to use my environment variables?

I want to be able to control tracing through configuration, not through an .ini file. But when I completely remove the ini file from my Azure function app, I get this exception:

```
Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager' threw an exception.
 ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Error reading the  directory.
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.StartRaisingEvents()
   at IBM.WMQ.MQClientCfg.CheckForMqclientIniFileChanges()
   at IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.NmqiEnvironment..ctor(NmqiPropertyHandler nmqiPropertyHandler)
   at IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.NmqiFactory.GetInstance(NmqiPropertyHandler properties)
   at IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager..cctor()
```

(this exception does not occur locally)

Comment: Have you confirmed that if you don't have the mqclient.ini settings in place that the launchSettings.json values are used? i.e. those fields are definitely specified correctly.

Comment: @MoragHughson yes, that works. If I use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MQDotnetTraceLevel")` in my C# code I get the value back from my launchsettings.json. I will update my question

Comment: I'm not sure whether your ability to retrieve your set environment variable is your proof that it works or whether it is an additional piece of information. If you have actually successfully created trace by removing the mqclient.ini settings and using the environment variable settings, but when you reinstate the mqclient.ini settings it goes back to those, then I suggest you contact IBM to open a case. If you have not yet done that test, then that was what I was asking about.

Comment: The reason I ask this (in case it is not obvious) is to prove that you have the correct spellings. I know in other environments (not familiar enough with .NET) that the environment variables are not spelled the same way as the mqclient.ini fields. I don't know if they are or are not the same spelling in the case of .NET, so that is why I asked if the tracing works when you remove the mqclient.ini settings.

Comment: What do you expect? A value of 1 or 2 are both expected to return a trace,  0 is supposed to turn it off as documented [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=applications-tracing-mq-net-mqclientini).  Have you tried setting the ENV variable to `0`?  Note that per the docs [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=applications-tracing-mq-net-using-environment-variables) the env variable is `MQDOTNET_TRACE_ON` not `MQDotnetTraceLevel`.  Also note that APAR IT44039 is opened but not yet closed stating that setting the `MQDOTNET_TRACE_ON` to any value enables trace.

Comment: `mqclient.ini` is more flexible since it is dynamic, you can update the file and turn trace on or off without restarting the application. Using ENV variables requires a application restart. IBM has confirmed that `mqclient.ini` is working a documented where ENV is not.

Comment: @JoshMc I would expect the trace files to be created inside the 'traces_from_environment_variables' directory, as that is the environment variable value that should override the ini setting. But with the ini file the traces are created in mq_traces and without the ini file nothing is created.

Comment: The ENV variables are not the same name as the INI settings.  Please read my comments and read the second link for the actual names.

Comment: tnx @JoshMc, I see what you mean now. I was able to configure tracing using environment variables MQDOTNET_TRACE_ON, MQTRACELEVEL and MQTRACEPATH. If you add this as an answer, then I can approve it.... (otherwise I'll answer it myself)

Comment: The weird thing is, with Azure Function app, that the mqclient.ini file does need to be in place, otherwise I get that FileNotFoundException.... But I've just added an empty one as I now configure it through environment variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=applications-tracing-mq-net-using-environment-variables) the environment variables used to control tracing are `MQDOTNET_TRACE_ON`, `MQTRACELEVEL` and `MQTRACEPATH` not `MQDotnetTraceLevel` and `MQDotnetTracePath`.